# Advice - CSS Flexible Layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a web application which pulls in some information about meeting rooms, an instance of my program has a variable amount of rooms, these range from 1 to around 15 meeting rooms. The meeting rooms are stored in a database.

At the moment there is a fixed 9 x 9 grid.

The page MUST fit it on one 32" monitor (1080p)

Is it possible to use some CSS code to dynamically change the layout so no matter how many rooms there are they will fit onto one page?

Thanks for you help, screenshot of existing system below.
[image]

```
.grid3x3 {
    display:table;
    height:85%; /*Leave some space for the title*/
    width:99%;  /*Should equal div width times number of columns*/
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top: 100px;
    left:10px;

}
.grid3x3 > div {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}

.grid3x3 > div > div {
    display:table-cell;

}

div {

height:33%;/*Change these to 100% divided by number of rows/columns that you have put in*/
width:33%; /*Change these to 100% divided by number of rows/columns that you have put in*/
}



#footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I haven't posted all of this because it will take up a lot of space but hopefully you get the picture..

```
<div class="grid3x3">
<div>
<div>
<h2> COM Meeting Room  <asp:Label runat="server" id="COMS"></asp:Label></h2>
<asp:Label runat="server" id="COMSMtgs"></asp:Label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell us how you display your grid? Table? UL/LI? It is necessary to give your a correct answer.

Comment: CSS Flexible Layout? How about [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)!

Comment: we are going to need your code to answer

Comment: Need your code as well as limitations regarding browser, etc as the answer would be different based on browser.

Comment: The answer is yes, you can. How to do it... depends on what you have.

Comment: The easiest way will be to use ul/li HTML list with : 1) parent container width 100% width; 2) li width align left and fix width (in percent or in px).

Comment: Still you could either just have all the meeting room container elements floated with fixed dimensions so they are all next to each other and simply wrap if they hit the horizontal end of the screen... or use `display: inline-block` for the same effect.  It shouldn't be hard to fit 12 boxes for meeting rooms on a 32" monitor.

Comment: I've posted what I have so far :)

Comment: and what about your HTML?

Comment: Posted a snippet, all of it would be unnecessary as its pretty self explanatory

Comment: @Ennui have you got any examples please?

Comment: for your `div` holding the info for each room just make sure they have fixed width and then either `float: left` or `display: inline-block` will tile them horizontally until they wrap upon running out of horizontal space.  Try removing all that CSS you have already as it's clearly confusing you.

Comment: @chadocat wrote an answer that should work fine for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make your grid 3*3 on a 1080p screen. On smaller screens, the rooms will display in 2 colums and on even smaller screens (less than 1280 px wide) 1 column.

You can change the number of columns for each screen size by changing the `min-width`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k4jgT/10/)**

CSS:

```
   .grid3x3 {
        text-align:center;

    }
    .grid3x3 > div {
        float:left;
        min-width:640px;
        width:33%;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, seems so simple now!